# jquery sumoSelect library how to get elements dropdown

Tags: jquery, sumoselect.js

I work with jquery sumoselect libray drop down.

I have the following sentence. Combonombre is the combo estacion

```
var num = $('select[name=' + combonombre + '] option').length;
```

This returns 59 but the combo estacion only has 15 elements.

I want to remove combo estacion elements and reload  them with new elements.

How can I get the 15 elements of estacion?

[image]

**EDITED**

I loaded the combo, and now I want to reload it . At the begining the combo has 59 elements but the new combo has 15. I want to delete these 59 elements and load the new 15 (data in the image)

I have the following code for loading the drop down

```
$.each(data, function (index, elemento) {

            $('select[name=' + combonombre + ']')[0].sumo.add(elemento.id,elemento.descripcion);
            $('select[name=' + combonombre + ']')[0].sumo.enableItem(index);

            var elementosCombos = $('select[name=' + combonombre + ']')[0].sumo.selectAll();

            if (valorSeleccionado==elemento.id) {

                $('select[name=' + combonombre + ']')[0].sumo.selectItem(elemento.descripcion);
            }
        });
```

The instruction

```
var elementosCombos = $('select[name=' + combonombre + ']')[0].sumo.selectAll();
```

returns undefined after add the element

Comment: post your select data content here

Comment: Edited the data

Comment: Post your html code as well

Comment: Hi please avoid posting image , also could you tell us how many select ( html code  ) you've created in your page

Comment: because using the selector `$('select[name=' + combonombre + '] option')` will loop through all the selects

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: @Carlota you have not provided your html code and how you updating your data. Provide full code instead of image.

Comment: I edited the code loading the drop down